# Why is my React Infinite Scrolling not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Main constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      page: 1,
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      isActive: false,
    };
  }
```

Using componentDidMount method

```
    async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=ff954e750b914328a0bc65c2e45304c4&page=1&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json(data);

    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      totalArticlesResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      loading: false,
    });
  }
```

Trying to debug in the console "testing", but this function (loadFunc) isn't trigger inside the

```
    loadFunc = async () => {
    console.log('testing');
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=ff954e750b914328a0bc65c2e45304c4&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json(data);
    this.setState({
      articles: [...this.state.articles, ...this.parsedData.articles],
      totalArticlesResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      loading: false
    })
  }
```

Rendering jsx and mapping through the elements from API

```
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="container my-3"> 
        {/* Infinite scrolling */}

        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.articles.length}
          next={this.loadFunc}
          hasMore={this.state.articles.length !== this.state.totalArticlesResults}
          loader={<Spinner />}
        >
```

container inside `InfiniteScroll` Component

```
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              {!this.state.loading && 
                this.state.articles.map((element, index) => {
```

returning in mapping

```
                  return (
                    <div className="col-md-4" key={index}>
                     ..
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component)

> children is by default assumed to be of type array and its length is used to determine if loader needs to be shown or not, if your children is not an array, specify this prop to tell if your items are 0 or more.

In your case you have only one child `<div className="container" />`.

The solution could be to change the render method to render an array of children. And I think the condition `!this.state.loading` is bad because it will blink and if the library rely on children as array, it can break the functionality.

Comment: what do you mean by change the render method to render an array of children. How to do that?